# Mysql join multiple tables with sum of fields

Tags: php, mysql

I need to get data from three tables.I have  four tables "orders", "ordersdetail","reserved" and "deliver". In "orders" table are pick orders for picking items from a warehouse, "ordersdetail" table contain the list of items to be picked, in "reserved" table are picked items and in "deliver" is the list of delivered items.These are the tables :

ordersdetail:

```
|ido|barcode | quantity| order_id|
==================================
| 1 |  123   |   2     |    1    |
| 2 |  456   |   1     |    1    |
| 3 |  789   |   3     |    1    |
| 4 |  456   |   1     |    2    |
```

reserved:

```
|idr|barcode | quantity| order_id|
==================================
| 1 |  123   |   1     |    1    |
| 2 |  123   |   1     |    1    |
| 3 |  456   |   1     |    1    |
| 4 |  789   |   1     |    1    |
| 5 |  456   |   1     |    2    |
```

deliver:

```
|idr|barcode | quantity| order_id|
==================================
| 1 |  123   |   1     |    1    |
| 2 |  456   |   1     |    1    |
| 3 |  456   |   1     |    2    |
```

I need an sql to get data for order_id=1 to sum quantity from tables grouped by barcode:

```
|order_id|barcode|order_qt|reserved_qt|delivered_qt|
====================================================
|    1   |  123  |   2    |    2      |     1      |
|    1   |  456  |   1    |    1      |     1      |
|    1   |  789  |   2    |    1      |     0      |
```

I tried with first two table but i cant get it:

```
SELECT m.barcode,m.quantity,m.order_id,(SELECT SUM(reserved.quantity) from reserved where reserved.barcode=m.barcode and reserved.order_id=m.order_id) FROM orderdetail AS m
```

Comment: Please share what query you have so far and exactly what you are having trouble with.

Comment: thank you Stu for your answer. I edited my question. I tried to get the results from two tables  but i cant get it. when i put the second condition in WHERE clause not summing the quantity at all

Comment: use left join for that.

Comment: @ahmet gül  i tryed also with : `code`

Comment: @ahmetgül  i tryed also with : SELECT orderdetail.*,COALESCE(sum(deliver.quantity),0) as reserved_qt FROM `orderdetail` LEFT JOIN `reserved` ON orderdetail.order_id=reserved.order_id group by orderdetail.order_id,reserved.barcode ORDER BY orderdetail.order_id ASC  but when summing is not grouped by barcode